# Can diff change the root path name in its output for patch files?

Tags: diff

You constantly see kernel patches where it's `a/subdir/file.c` `b/subdir/file.c`.  Say in reality you have `linux-5.10.37_org` and `linux-5.10.37_mod`, is there a way to get the `a` and `b` output without having to rename the directories?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’d have to post-process the patch to do this, but you don’t need to: the base directory names are ignored in most cases. `a` and `b` aren’t real directories, they are the names produced for patches representing changes in a `git` repository.

If you really want to produce `git`-style patches for the kernel, the best way is to use `git`. However, in your case the following would work:

```
sed -i -e s/linux-5.10.37_org/a/ -e s/linux-5.10.37_mod/b/ mypatch.patch
```